# robots.txt file Question

Tags: google, robots.txt

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:
User-agent: *
Disallow: /account.php
Disallow: /cart.php
```

Is the above actually blocking crawlers? i just saw the extra "disallow" after the Google

Answer (score 3):

When you have Disallow followed by nothing, that effectively means "allow all":

```
Disallow:
```

If you want to block all, that's:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

So, in your example, you are allowing Mediapartners-Google access to everything, and then disallowing all other crawlers from these two pages:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /account.php
Disallow: /cart.php
```

Comment: Thank you, My worry was that by having Disallow: User-agent: *, that meant that i was overiding and telling everyone not to crawl ( in essence, meaning not allow any user agents ( crawlers )

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is not a valid robots.txt. Parsers may understand it anyway, but you can’t be sure, especially not for the future.

Each record needs to be separated by at least one blank line.

So your robots.txt should look like:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /account.php
Disallow: /cart.php
```

Meaning of this robots.txt:

- the bot `Mediapartners-Google` may crawl all resources
- all others bots may crawl all resources except those whose URL paths start with `account.php` resp. `cart.php`.

Comment: Since the default is to allow all, you don't even need the first two lines.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: This would change the meaning. With these two lines, `Mediapartners-Google` is allowed to crawl `account.php` and `cart.php`. If you omit these two lines, the `Mediapartners-Google` bot would fall under `User-agent: *`, and so it would not be allowed to crawl those URLs anymore.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: The bot `Mediapartners-Google` doesn’t have to check for the `User-agent: *` record. `User-agent: *` is ONLY for those bots that are not matched by any other record. I don’t know if or if not Google implemented their parsers correctly, but this is from the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html): "default access policy for any robot that has not matched any of the other records"

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: I tested Google’s implementation in GWT: it works in the way it should (as I described): `/cart.php` is allowed for `Mediapartners-Google` and disallowed for all other bots.

Comment: Sorry you are correct! I misread the output in GWT, my bad.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, you have three lines here:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google Disallow: User-agent: *
Disallow: /account.php
Disallow: /cart.php
```

You can get detailed info about the Google crawler [from them](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en)